# PHP & MySQL store userid after login complete sessions

Tags: php, mysql, session

Alright so this is my login.php page's php code file:

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['action'])) {
        switch (strtolower($_GET['action'])) {
            case 'login':
                if (isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
                    if (!validateUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {
                        $_SESSION['error'] = "Bad username or password supplied.";
                        unset($_GET['action']);
                    }
                }else {
                    $_SESSION['error'] = "Username and Password are required to login.";
                    unset($_GET['action']);
                }           
            break;
            case 'logout':
                if (loggedIn()) {
                    logoutUser();
                    header ("Location: ".$domainNow);
                }else {
                    unset($_GET['action']);
                }
            break;
        }
    }
    if (loggedIn()) {
        header ("Location: ".$domainNow);
    }elseif (!isset($_GET['action'])) {
        $sUsername = "";
        if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
            $sUsername = $_POST['username'];
        }

        $sError = "";
        if (isset($_SESSION['error'])) {
            $sError = '<span id="error">' . $_SESSION['error'] . '</span><br />';
        }

        $sOutput .= '<h2>Login to NextGenStep</h2><br />
                ' . $sError . '
                <form name="login" method="post" action="/user-action/login">
                    Username: <input type="text" name="username" value="' . $sUsername . '" /><br />
                    Password: &nbsp;<input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br /><br />
                    <div style="padding-left:71px;"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login!" /></div>
                </form>
            <div style="padding-left:131px;"><h4>Create a new <a href="/register">account</a>?</h4></div>';
    }
    echo $sOutput;
?>
```

I'm new to PHP and MySQL together, so what I want here is to get the user id (column name is uid) from the database AFTER the user has logged in, but I also want it to store the user id in a session so I can use it on other pages. I have already session_start(); declared on an include file so I don't have to do it manually on every page.

Also, here is my loggedIn function on my include page:

```
function loggedIn() {
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) && isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: So are you having an issue or what is the your trouble you are running into?

Comment: As I said, I want to store the user id as a session AFTER the user has successfully logged in, but I just don't know how to get it. I tried running a simple mysql query: SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = . $_SESSION['username'] . 
But it didn't quite work.

Answer (score 0):

Just save the UID in a session variable, eg;

```
$_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
```

Remember to use `session_start();` before attempting to use `$_SESSION` variables, or it will be undefined.

By the way, your `loggedIn()` function should have a false return as well as a true return. I would use this;

```
function loggedIn() {
    return ((isset($_SESSION['loggedin']) and isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? true : false); 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Saving the uid as a session variable will just cause me to get an undefined variable error on my page.

Comment: You need to start the session at the top of each page of code that you want to use `$_SESSION` variables (or in your controller if you have one). `session_start();`

Comment: As I mentioned on the post, I have already declared session_start(); on a php page I include on every page.

Comment: Are you sure that include file is being included properly, or perhaps you're ending the session when you shouldn't.

Comment: Why not just `return isset($_SESSION['loggedin'], $_SESSION['username']);`?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure the file is being included.
`<?php include("globalDb.php"); ?>` is on the top of my page on login.php, and my globalDb.php contains: 
`<?php
 session_start();
 $dbhost="localhost"; 
 $dbusername="root"; 
 $dbpassword="root"; 
 $dbname="lol";
 
 $connect = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbusername, $dbpassword);
 $db = mysql_select_db($dbname,$connect) or die ("Error: Could not connect to the database.");
?>`

Comment: @Gumbo Does it matter? It's just what I would do should I wish to change the return values in the future.

Comment: @EmirPeskovic And `globalDb.php` is included at the top of every page?

Comment: What happens if you explicitly use `session_start();` at the top of login.php?

Comment: @worldofjr Probably nothing will change, but I don't know, I'm not an expert. I just know that if I don't use it in my include file, I will have to use it on every page.

Comment: @worldofjr Well, I just did, and that just messed everything up. Suddenly, logged in users would see content only logged out users see, you can't access any page a logged in user SHOULD be able to, nor can you log out. And all that just by removing `session_start();` from the include file.
Maybe I should just redo the whole user system?

Comment: No, don't remove `session_start();` from the include. Just explicitly state it in login.php

Comment: Or else it's because I'm including too many pages for it all to work as it should, because to be honest, I am quite lazy when it comes to editing things, so if I find anything that I may edit in the future, I'm adding it in a seperate file which I will just include when needed. For example, the footer.

Comment: Oh, that won't work. I already tried that earlier, gave me this error: `Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start()`

Comment: Do you have **any** `$_SESSION` references before starting the session, for example the `loggedIn()` function in a file that is included before the database connection include.

Comment: If all you are doing is trying to retrieve your `uid`, provided it's stored in your db, if you are having issues retrieving it, then it maybe your sql statement that is flawed. For instance, you commented that `SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = . $_SESSION['username']` doesn't work, but if this is literally how you wrote it, that is incorrect, so it for sure won't retrieve it.

Comment: @Rasclatt nono, I wrote it like this: `$sql = mysql_query("SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = " . $_SESSION['username'] . "");` and then executed it via mysql_fetch_array.

Comment: Check my answer, but you would need to write it: `"SELECT uid FROM users WHERE username = '" . $_SESSION['username'] . "'"`

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve your UID from your database, provided it's been written there and not empty try (well either way, empty or not empty):

```
class FetchUID
    {
        public static function execute($_uid='')
            {
                if(!empty($_uid)) {
                        // I am pressuming you have a global database engine
                        // If not, retrieve your engine however at this point.
                        // For sake of ease, I am pretending it's a global....
                        global $con;

                        // I use PDO so this is how I would get it
                        // I am also making the statement broad just to make sure it is retrieving at all
                        $query  =   $con->prepare("select * from users where username ='$_uid'");
                        $query->execute();

                        if($query->rowCount() == 1)
                            $user_info  =   $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
                        else
                            $user_info['uid']   =   self::Write();
                    }

                return (isset($user_info['uid']) && !empty($user_info['uid']))? $user_info['uid']:'error';

            }

        protected static function Write()
            {
                // Code here that creates the custom uid and returns it again
            }
    }

// Check that the session->username is set + that the session->uid is NOT set
if(isset($_SESSION['username']) && !isset($_SESSION['uid'])) {
        // If set, fetch it via above class & methods
        $uid    =   FetchUID::execute($_SESSION['username']);
        // Write your $uid
        echo $uid;
        // Sessionize it
        $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
    }
```